# How to compare two columns in a table to highlight its difference using PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a table with three columns. The sample data is below.

```
DEL_NUM     REF_NO1   REF_NO2
4785987568  5487M     5487
123468556   12365M    12365
1256785987  7859      7859
2583697412  1478569M  1478569M
1478523698  78958M    6558125
```

I want to compare the value of the two columns `REF_NO1` and `REF_NO2` so that I can highlight the differences in the values in the two columns.

Example

For first row the difference is M

For second row the difference is M

For third row the difference is null

For fourth row diff is null

For fifth row the whole value is different 78958M

Comment: then why tagged as Sql server???

Comment: So what are you using? MySQL, SQL Server or Oracle? You added a tag for each of them? And if you are using PL/SQL you should add the code of your stored procedure as well.

Comment: I am using Oracle db..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is REF_NO2 always a substring of REF_NO1? Then you could do...

```
SELECT REPLACE(REF_NO1,REF_NO2,'') as diff from mytable
```

Comment: In most cases it will be a substring so the above query highlights the differences as is the requirement.

Comment: One observation - REPLACE will replace all occurrences of the string, so if REF_NO1 is "123123M" and REF_NO2 is "123", it would return "M". Don't know if you have cases like that or whether that would be a problem...

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can do it, i.e. replace the first string with `''` from 2nd string and will give you the difference

```
mysql> select replace('5487M','5487','') as diff ; 
+------+
| diff |
+------+
| M    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select replace('12365M','12365','') as diff ; 
+------+
| diff |
+------+
| M    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select replace('7859','7859','') as diff ; 
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|      |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select replace('78958M','6558125','') as diff ; 
+--------+
| diff   |
+--------+
| 78958M |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the final query could be as

```
select replace(REF_NO1,REF_NO2,'') as diff
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of 'replace' function.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

MYSQL:

```
SELECT if(length(REPLACE(REF_NO1,REF_NO2,''))>0,REPLACE(REF_NO1,REF_NO2,''),null) as diff
FROM   table
```

ORACLE:

```
SELECT case when length(REPLACE(REF_NO1,REF_NO2,''))>0 then REPLACE(REF_NO1,REF_NO2,'') else null end as diff
FROM   table
```

Comment: The error thrown is 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 46'

Comment: Its Oracle error.. For oracle I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If this is a homework assignment, then you already have some pretty good answers. Otherwise, I would claim that this is precisely the kind of processing that should take place at the app/UI level. There are several good reasons for this, especially if you intend to manipulate the display of the data like you did in your question to emphasize where the difference occurs. But mostly remember that when you can process in even interpreted languages like Java or C# rather than SQL, the difference is like running downhill rather than slogging through knee-deep mud.